# Existing VB console app needs web interface - Best approach?

Tags: asp.net, sockets, tcp, embeddedwebserver

I have a visual basic console application that monitors/controls water flow.  It 'listens' on a TCP/IP socket and responds to simple commands sent to 
its port.

Naturally since it has recently been documented, it needs to change.

It is now requested that the VB application also display a very simple web page to allow users to control waterflow thru a browser as
well as thru TCP/IP commands.

I am new to web programming, can anyone suggest the most straightforward way to add a simple web interface to an existing VB console application or do I need to start with a VB website project and somehow get it to 'listen' to a tcp/ip socket?

Comment: You could create a web page that sends commands to the console application via a message queue once it receives them.

Comment: This looks like a great suggestion, thank you @EJoshuaS.

Comment: Can you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add my comment as an answer, you could create the Web site as a separate project and have it send the console application commands via a message queue.

This would have the advantage of making it relatively easy for you to vary them independently of each other give the fairly loose coupling between them; in fact, using that the console application wouldn't really care what kind of application was on the "other end" of the message queue, so you'd have greater flexibility in your implementation.

Comment: Used this idea and worked just as expected - thank you again.